# Objective-C float #define not accessible in Swift4

Tags: objective-c, swift4

I am migrating code from Objective-C to Swift 4.0. Here I have some float #define constants related to my deviceHeight in Specific Objective-C header class. While accessing this #define giving error `"Use of unresolved identifier"`. When I use Objective-C string #define identifier it's easily accessible within Swift class.

Not accessible in Swift4

**#define PHONE_IPHONE10          PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT==812.0f**

Accessible in Swift4

**#define ERROR                               @"Some error occured. Please try later."**

Help me with your comments or solution.

Comment: Why don't you use constants? Changing `#define` to constant is easy: `static CGFloat const PHONE_IPHONE10 PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT = 812.;`
then you can also use consts in `swift`
Getting phone screen you can also achieve programically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475008/how-to-get-iphone-screen-size-programatically

Comment: But why Swift has restricted for float and not for string #define?

Comment: Because it is dangerous. Imagine this situation: `#define aa = 10`
then somewhere in your code could be `let anotherVar = "smaall value"`
anotherVar will be `sm10ll value`

Comment: I hope that I get this solution in Swift 4.2 or 5...:D

Comment: No, you will not, because Swift is safe (if we talk about types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this imports to Swift...

> #define ERROR @"Some error occured. Please try later."

...is that it’s semantically equivalent to a constant declaration. That is, it permanently associates that string-literal value with the name `ERROR`. The Swift compiler recognizes that you’re using the C preprocessor to define a constant, and translates it to a Swift constant.

(Even though you could—and probably should—define C global constants without the preprocessor, Swift recognizes that there’s a long tradition of using `#define` instead, and imports it anyway.)

---

The reason this doesn’t import to Swift...

> #define PHONE_IPHONE10 PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT==812.0f

...is that this is a preprocessor *macro*. It doesn’t statically map a name to a value. Instead, it tells C that wherever it sees your name `PHONE_IPHONE10`, it should substitute the *expression* `PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT==812.0f`. Presumably `PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT` is itself a macro, so the whole thing expands to a chain of method calls and an equality comparison.

Swift itself doesn’t do preprocessor macros, or anything like such, so it doesn’t import them from C.

A close equivalent would be to redefine this logic using a computed property or function (and the idiomatic way to do that in Swift would be as a static member on a type, not a global symbol). Something like this:

```
extension UIDevice {
    class var isMaybeiPhoneX: Bool {
        return false // or some logic based on UIScreen.main.size
    }
}
```

But be warned, the whole idea of conditionally changing your app’s UI or behavior based on a specific screen height check is fraught with peril. Tried Auto Layout?

Answer (score -1):

To achieve similar functionality I created Constants.swift file with this structure:

```
struct Constants {
    struct phoneHeights {
        static let PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT = 812.0
        //some others consts
    }

    struct iPhoneX {
        static let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = 44
        //some others consts
    }
}
```

Or simply:

```
struct Constants {
    static let PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT = 812.0
    static let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = 44
}
```

And for type safety in Swift, you can read [here](http://www.dummies.com/programming/macintosh/type-safety-in-swift/).

Comment: That is not the same as the above macro. The above macro is a comparison, not an assignment. Your answer would be correct if the original code was `#define PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT   812.0f`.

Comment: @uliwitness Yes and because of that I wrote "similar functionality"